Installing PLV8 extension for Postgresql under RHEL os
I want to ask if there anyone who installed PostgreSQL 15 with the PLv8 extension on RedHat 9 since I want to make sure if the combination that I am using works just fine, otherwise I might need someone who might help me troubleshoot the installation issues that I am having below and those are the steps that I undertook:

Used a Redhat 9 VM and installed PostgreSQL from this main page by selecting the version and OS required,
then, i went to the PLV8 extension GitHub repository

2- Used git clone command to save the source files on my system under the extension directory which was
"/usr/pgsql-15/share/extension/plv8" in my case, also made sure before installing anything on the system that the os is up to date using "sudo dnf update"
3- Used the following commands in order to enable postgres on boot
"sudo systemctl start postgresql" and
"sudo systemctl enable postgresql"
4- Used "make PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_config" to make sure this points to the right location, just to make sure that pg_config is in PATH environment and please note down that was a fix to another error that I got that was saying "pg_config" does not exit.
5- Finally, got this error:
Makefile:121: /usr/pgsql-15/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: * No rule to make target '/usr/pgsql-15/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
6- I checked the pgxs.mk location using "/usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_config --pgxs"
I had the following output:
"/usr/pgsql-15/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk"
then I used make command again and I got the screenshot below.
make command image
I've been having this issue for few weeks and tried everything I could and the thing is I can't use another OS, PostgreSQL version or another extension, since those are the project's requirements, I would really appreciate any help you can provide.
Thanks in advance,

